# When using "azd up" to deploy a .net Aspire application, is it possible to also deploy the related Azure resources (components)?

Tags: .net, azure, .net-8.0, dotnet-aspire

When creating a .net Aspire application with [Azure components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/aspire/fundamentals/components-overview?tabs=dotnet-cli) such as the Service Bus, I have to create the resource on Azure first, before I can run the application locally.

When I finally deploy the application using "azd up", a new resource group gets created and now I end up with 2.

What are my options to have everything I need under a single resource group?
Would it be possible for "azd up" to also provision the related/required azure resources such as service bus, storage accounts and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plan is to enable this before we ship v1, but right now there's no easy way to reuse the same resource group unless you tweak the bicep that azd generates. You can use [`azd infra synth`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspire/deployment/azure/aca-deployment-azd-in-depth?tabs=macos#generate-bicep-from-net-aspire-app-model) to spit out the bicep and you can customize it from there to do what you want (assumes you know bicep).

Comment: I'm Glad to know this is in the road map and I'm looking forward to v1. I don't think the bicep route is worth it for what I'm doing now but, it is good to know the option is out there if needed. Thanks a bunch.